# How to calculate sample weights to match population in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [20,30,40], 'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'F'],
                   'Origin': ['Caucasian', 'Asian', 'Latino']})
```

which represent a sample from a population. I want to calculate sample weights for `dt` and add them as a new column.
My population has the following ratios for each of the features:

- `Gender` -> M:F = 1:1 (meaning for every 1 Male there is 1 Female and vice versa)
- `Age` -> 20:30:40 = 1:2:3
- `Origin` -> caucasian:asian:latino = 1:4:2

How can I calculate the weights ?

**UPDATE**

The weights should have the following property:
When you do e.g. `dt.groupby('Gender')['Weight'].sum()` you should get

```
Gender
F    1
M    1
```

since the ratio for `gender` is `1:1`,

when you do e.g. `dt.groupby('Origiin')['Weight'].sum()` you should get

```
Origin
Asian        4
Caucasian    1
Latino       2
```

and when you do e.g. `dt.groupby('Age')['Weight'].sum()` you should get

```
Age
20    1
30    2
40    3
```

Comment: What you want is unclear, what is the exact expected output?

Comment: @mozway added an update

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume `a`, `b`, and `c` the weights:

```
   Age Gender     Origin Weight
0   20      M  Caucasian      a
1   30      F      Asian      b
2   40      F     Latino      c
```

You want M:F = 1:1, thus `a = b+c`, and 20:30:40 = 1:2:3, thus `30 * a = 20 * b` and `a * 2 = c`.

You can solve the first 2 equations, giving:

```
b = 2/3 * a
c = a / 3
```

Which is incompatible with the third equation (`a * 2 = c`, unless `a = b = c = 0`) and I'm not even considering here the conditions on `Origin`.

So in summary, what your want is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

First, define the sample population ratios

```
gender_ratio = 1 # the ration is 1:1
age_ratio = {'20': 1, '30': 2, '40': 3} # 1:2:3
origin_ratio = {'Caucasian': 1, 'Asian': 4, 'Latino': 2} #1:4:2
```

Then, calculate the weight from the sample population and add it as a new column to the `dt`:

```
dt['Weight'] = dt.apply(lambda row: gender_ratio * age_ratio[str(row['Age'])] * origin_ratio[row['Origin']], axis=1)
```

Comment: added an update. your answer does not give the same output, please have a look